# Pointing datasource to correct folder

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have built my application in c# and have an sql compact DB to go along with it. What do I need to change the location to in order for it to point to the same directory as the application.

For example:

Right now my DB is in C\Windows blah blah...

And in my code I make the source point to that...when I build the project my app is in bin\release along with my DB file, but in my code the source is not pointed to this DB file..does anyone know what I need to insert to point it to the correct DB file?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Is it always going to be in the same directory as the application executable? If so, perhaps you can just set the connection string using the path of the current assembly (assuming everything is in the same place):

```
string curPath = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "MyDatabase.sdf");
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(String.Format("Data Source = {0}; Password ={1}", curPath , ":PASSWORD:");
```